# Linux VIM : Omnicppcomplete + supertab use bash color theme

Tags: linux, vim, colors, omnicppcomplete, supertab

I use vim with omnicppcomplete and supertab for programming. The dropdown window, which shows possible completions is like pink. How can i change the color for example to my personal bash color theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open your colorscheme.
2. Find the lines that start with `hi Pmenu*`.
3. Edit them to your liking.

If there's no such line in your colorscheme, add the lines below and change the colors to what you want:

```
hi Pmenu        cterm=none ctermfg=White     ctermbg=Black
hi PmenuSel     cterm=none ctermfg=Black     ctermbg=DarkGreen
hi PmenuSbar    cterm=none ctermfg=none      ctermbg=Green
hi PmenuThumb   cterm=none ctermfg=DarkGreen ctermbg=DarkGreen
```

See `:help :highlight` for more.

Comment: which colorscheme? .bashrc? I use a theme for the bash, which seems to include a nice syntax highlighting for the vim. I did not make a own color theme for the vim in my /.vim folder and did not put anything in my .vimrc according to colors.

Comment: Then put those lines at the end of your `~/.vimrc`.